# Getting the text which are in labels at particular cells

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone .I have small doubt that is,

first of all showing my output screen is below
[image: this is my output which is in simulator]

Here When i click DownloadAll button in navigationbar.I have to get the names which are in the cells which is having an image Download.

How it is possible if any body know this please help me...

Comment: How are you populating the cells with the data? I guess you have any array of data from which you can find out which rows do have an image download button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same condition which you are using in  cellForRowAtIndexPath to check which image to display download or checkmark.The same condition you can use to get the names.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the name on click of download button .. then simply you can access those data from array ... by which you are populating the data in table view....